# Decimal Keyboard not showing in iOS after switching fields

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, decimal, cordova-ios

To get the numbers with decimal characters in keyboard of iOS, I tried almost every trick in js and jquery (tel as input type, 0.01 as step etc...) but the only solution was the plugins:

https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard

https://github.com/gbrits/cordova-plugin-ios-decimal-keyboard

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard-wkwebview

...

They are all working. However...

If there are more than one input fields after each other and if you switch from a "non-decimal" field to our "decimal" input field (either by arrows or by just tapping with fingers), you don't see the decimal character anymore, but just the numbers. If you unclick/click on "Done" and select the decimal input field again, it works then again.

This is the common problem of all the plugins. I'm asking myself whether it is a known issue or it is a very specific problem of my case?

This is my html:

```
<input v-if="isIOS" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" decimal="true" decimal-char="," 
       maxlength="10" min="0" :max="detailsSelectedPunt.tMax" placeholder="Punt..." v-model="detailsSelectedPunt.Number">


<input type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Commentaar..." v-model="detailsSelectedPunt.Commentaar">
```

Comment: having the same issue

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you been able to resolve this issue?